# How to open url in new browser tab from Web browser control (displaying PDF having a link) c#

Tags: c#, pdf, webbrowser-control, activereports

I am facing this issue, working on ***Active reports 9***. Every thing is fine as per our application we generate the report and in UI user will be viewing in a c# *Web browser control*.

Now the issue am facing is when client(user) clicks on the **link** present in pdf i.e. on Web Browser control. With in the same window the link is opening. They want the link to open in new window.

The problem q=am facing is if its Html control i would have used target="_blank" property but not , and its a windows application i cant even use Java script. I just gone through the properties of Picture control used in Report, theres only Hyperlink property which states in pdf it converts it to href or a tag.

Need some assistance as soon as possible is that possible to do in web browser control or should change any properties for picture control in Code behind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this help you. It worked for me.

Add the Navigating event on your webBrowser control. This will open the link in a new Browser window. In my case Google Chrome.

```
private void webBrowser1_Navigating(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!(e.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("file") || e.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("pdf")))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    //Open Link
                    Process.Start(e.Url.ToString());
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
               //Handle Exception
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Jacques Prinsloo, its working fine. I thought its not possible but u helped me. Thanks once again